# what to cover blocked sticky paint on my deck

Tags: painting

I have sanded my deck down to the primer but the sticky paint is still evident in the cracks and crevasses.  What can I paint over it with so that I can re-paint it?

Comment: not sure what it is you want to do? If you want to paint your deck (using PAINT), and you have sanded off an old layer(s), you don't need to care what is in the "cracks" (Im assuming you mean the grain). As long as you have scored the wood, and CLEAN CLEAN CLEAN CLEANED it, then when dry, repaint.  The thing to note here is that if you dont have a clean scoured surface, the paint potentially wont stick. Now, if you want to stain it, or "stain paint" it, then you will need to sand more, or pressure wash. Use a laquer thinner, etc. To regain the beauty of the wood.

Comment: To get a good answer you will need to fill in the backstory of what you mean by "sticky paint".

Comment: I used Glidden exterior paint, not realizing that this is not for walked-on surfaces.  That's beside the point, this paint I used never dried, it stayed sort of sticky. I understand that this is called blocked paint? I wanted to get rid of it anyway so I got on my all-fours and sanded it off to where I can see mostly the primer but some of the "sticky" brown paint can be seen. I am wondering if I have to cover the whole thing over with something besides another coat of primer in order to paint the deck with the right kind of paint. Thanks to everyone who can help me with this.

Comment: noybman, yes I do want to paint over it. So cleaning it good with do it, then. Ok thank you.

Comment: To @harper 's point - given that this paint never dried, and you are calling it "blocked paint" are you referring to Masonry paint? Or are you saying you have an issue because you used a latex primer and an oil paint or some other bad mix? I would suggest something like a wire brush (dont go crazy) and use a thinner. Then wash it, give it a light sanding, and prime/paint it. You don;t want to try to bond new paint to paint that is itself, not bonded.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

The paint didn't dry because it's complete junk.  Surprising to say that about Glidden.  Or, alternately, you insisted on painting wood while it was still wet.  Either wet from recent rain, or wet from initial manufacture - either was never dried out in the first place, or was treated.

Paint is only as good as the substrate (surface underneath).  Painting over a compromised surface is a lost cause, and the new paint will simply fail in the same manner as the failed paint.

All that paint has to go.  Good news, it's latex paint which is water-soluble and ridiculously easy to work with (as opposed to, say, aircraft LPU, the way you remove that from a fingernail is grow out the fingernail.)

Get yourself a decent scrub brush, e.g. the kind used to clean tubs. Keep the deck really wet and go to town.  If it's not even drying, it certainly won't survive an onslaught with solvent (that being water) and a stiff brush.    I would not use a wire-brush as that will dig into the wood.

If that doesn't work, or if that's actually oil paint, then you may need to go to a paint stripper.

In the future, don't use janky old paint you find in your garage.  To dispose of dodgy paint, leave the lid off until it all dries out and after a few months, huck it in the trash.  With oil paints (not nearly as likely to go bad), paint something you do not want, then throw it away.  If someone has a construction project nearby and a dumpster full of sheet refuse, go to town.

Walked-on surfaces are difficult.  DO NOT USE garage floor paint or any product called "Epoxy" where the sun's rays will touch it - UV light [destroys epoxy](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/103374/47125) unless you follow with an *additional* topcoat.  Sadly the only topcoat I've found that stands up stronger than epoxy (and protects it) is aircraft LPU.

Comment: I find my pressure washer with warm water and a lower pressure works great on removing latex (this kind of paint) don't use straight hot above 100 deg F or your pressure washer will need a seal kit or mine did at 135deg F.